# std::vector<std::pair<const int, const int> >::clear() VS 2010 no-compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code does not compile in Visual Studio 2010. Why?

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<const int, const int> > myVec;
    for(int i=0; i<88; ++i)
        myVec.push_back(std::make_pair<const int, const int>(1,i));
    myVec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

If I leave out the line that clears the vector, it works fine. I want an empty myVec. Cannot erase either. pop_back works. std::swap doesn't.

Comment: If it will not compile, show us the compiler error.

Comment: The whole point of `std::make_pair` is to not specify the template arguments. Let them be deduced. Also, you can't store `const` things in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Error 1 error C2166: l-value specifies const object c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility 260

Answer (score 3):

Clear operations on vector require that the element type satisfies `MoveAssignable` (see table 100 in `[C++11: 23.2.3]`), which a pair of `const` `int`s clearly does not.

As such, your program is invalid C++.

Do not store `const` elements. Expose the vector itself as `const` if you like.

Comment: I only checked the latest publicly available working copy.
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

It does not require MoveAssignable. Why would you move anything in a vector::clear() ? Is the standard really different?

Comment: the program compiles in g++
std::pair<const int, const int> is MoveAssignable at least it can be std::move()-ed and std::is_move_assignable<std::pair<const int, const int> >::value is true.

Comment: @user2863598: `std::move` doesn't actually perform a move.